# PHP : 10 files in dir delete old one and add new one

Tags: php, loops, rename

guys i have 10 Files in folder and Maximum 10 files are allowed.
When we add/upload new one the old one should be get delete.

i have one idea, don't know its appropriate or not.

```
Dir
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
4.jpg
5.jpg
6.jpg
7.jpg
8.jpg
9.jpg
10.jpg
```

My idea is delete no. 10 and rename rest from number 2 and upload new file as no.1 
Please share your idea and batter way to do it. 
Thanks.

Comment: better put a unique name once (like a timestamp) and sort them by that in descending order when reading the folder. there is no reason to rename constantly all the files.

Comment: Regarding how to keep X newest files, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60002347/how-to-delete-the-old-files-from-a-directory-if-a-condition-is-true-in-php/60002698#60002698